# i have a firebase databse from which i want to access some nested nodes then add a list of data to that particular node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase DB whose structure is like this :
[databse structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HYqy.png)

The pages node is a list of an array as [0,1,2,3...]. Now I want to get the reference to the each pages node child "data" and then the child node "meetingRooms" and then add a new child node in "meetingRooms" node which will be again a list of the "pages" node.

This is the code that i have tried so far
//for reference to databse

```
 mMeetingRoomsDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/pages").child("/data");
```

then to add data to Firebase :

```
public void updateBookings(){
    String startTime = "9:00 am";
    String endTime = "11:00 am";
    Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("startTime" , startTime);
    values.put("endTime" , endTime);
    values.put("bookingRoomId" , meetingRoomId);
    values.put("date" , resultDate);
    values.put("userUid" , userGoogleId);
    DatabaseReference ref = mMeetingRoomsDatabaseReference.child("/meetingRooms").child("bookings");
    ref.push().updateChildren(values);
}
```

then calling this method on a button click.
this is adding a completely new node to the "pages" node in the firebase like this : 
[after adding the data the firebase structure is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3p0G.png)

can anyone help me out that what I am doing wrong here? Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are missing a child. You actual `DatabaseReference` is:

```
mMeetingRoomsDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/pages").child("/data");
```

and you need to change it like this:

```
mMeetingRoomsDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("pages")
    .child("0") //This child was missing
    .child("data");
```

The is an example for a particular one named -> "0". You can change this with an actual variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but the pages node is list and the data will get pushed based on the item selected in the recycelrview. so is there a way to not hardcode the .child("0") and make it automatic ?

Comment: every child in the "pages" node is a property item , so the data will pushed based on the the item selected by the user.So i can't really use .child("0") , it will limit me to push the data onlly to that node.

Comment: As i said, the code above is only as an example. You can get the item position, store into a variable and use it in your `DatabaseReference`. In stead of having `.child("0")`, you'll need to have `.child(itemPosition)`

Comment: how can i miss that part --lame . I was scratching my head for hours . Thanks man @alex